# System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'Android.Graphics.Drawables.ScaleDrawable'

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, syncfusion

While using sfprogressbar we are getting an Appcenter Error.
ProgressBarBase.ApplyDrawableColor (Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable drawable, Android.Graphics.Color color, Android.Graphics.PorterDuff+Mode mode)
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'Android.Graphics.Drawables.ScaleDrawable .
Why this error occurred and how to resolve this error.

> 

```
Java.Interop
JniPeerMembers.AssertSelf (Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self)
Java.Interop
JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters)
Android.Graphics.Drawables
Drawable.SetTint (System.Int32 tintColor)
Syncfusion.Android.ProgressBar
ProgressBarBase.ApplyDrawableColor (Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable drawable, Android.Graphics.Color color, Android.Graphics.PorterDuff+Mode mode)
Syncfusion.Android.ProgressBar
SfLinearProgressBar.SetProgressColor ()
Syncfusion.Android.ProgressBar
ProgressBarBase.set_ProgressColor (Android.Graphics.Color value)
Syncfusion.XForms.Android.ProgressBar
ProgressBarUtility.OnLinearBarPropertyChanged (Syncfusion.Android.ProgressBar.SfLinearProgressBar native, Syncfusion.XForms.ProgressBar.SfLinearProgressBar control, System.String propertyName)
Syncfusion.Android.ProgressBar
SfLinearProgressBar.OnLinearProgressBarPropertiesChanged (System.Object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
(wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void_object_PropertyChangedEventArgs(object,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs)
Xamarin.Forms
BindableObject.OnPropertyChanged (System.String propertyName)
Xamarin.Forms
Element.OnPropertyChanged (System.String propertyName)
Xamarin.Forms
BindableObject.SetValueActual (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+BindablePropertyContext context, System.Object value, System.Boolean currentlyApplying, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.SetValueFlags attributes, System.Boolean silent)
Xamarin.Forms
BindableObject.SetValueCore (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.SetValueFlags attributes, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+SetValuePrivateFlags privateAttributes)
Xamarin.Forms
BindingExpression.ApplyCore (System.Object sourceObject, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject target, Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Boolean fromTarget)
Xamarin.Forms
BindingExpression.Apply (System.Boolean fromTarget)
Xamarin.Forms
BindingExpression+BindingExpressionPart.<PropertyChanged>b__49_0 ()
Xamarin.Forms
BindingExpression+BindingExpressionPart.PropertyChanged (System.Object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
Xamarin.Forms
BindingExpression+WeakPropertyChangedProxy.OnPropertyChanged (System.Object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
(wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void_object_PropertyChangedEventArgs(object,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs)
```